# creating a column checker where on column is NA and another one has a specific element

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

So I am trying to create a column checker where I have column1 and column 2. What I am trying to accomplish, is have it so that if there is an element in column 2, then to check column 1 so that it is a specific element like a certain status.

example, if column 2 is not null, then column 1 should be something specific, if not then I want to put that it is an error.

Here is what I tried:
Im using the tidyverse library

```
df %>% mutate(check_column = ifelse(!is.na(column2) & filter(column2 == "Closed"), 'Check', 'Error'))
```

if it helps to visualize what im trying to accomplish. Column 2 is a date, though transformed as a character just for ease of manipulation. The data set I want to use this for has errors. Like for example column 1 would equal "Open" but have a date on column 2 which is an error (same row), and that is what I am trying to flag as error.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need the `filter` statement.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
     mutate(check_column = ifelse(!is.na(column2) & column2 == "Closed", 
        'Check', 'Error'))
```

If it is based on two columns

```
df %>% 
     mutate(check_column = ifelse(!is.na(column2) & column1 == "Closed", 
        'Check', 'Error'))
```

If we want to check for multiple elements

```
df %>% 
  mutate(check_column = case_when(!is.na(column2) & column1 %in% 
           c("Closed", "pending") ~ "Check", TRUE ~ "Error"))
```

---

Or another option is

```
df %>%
    mutate(check_column = case_when(column2 %in% "Closed" 
               ~ "Check", TRUE ~ "Error"))
```

Comment: Thank you this helps very much. I particular like your example 2. Its actually what I think I did earlier but must have put like an extra space somewhere because when I did it it didnt work.   Only thing, is there a way to modify it further, because it does give the right check, but will also give an error when example column1 == "pending" and column 2 is null, which is correct and should have a check.

Comment: oops sorry, you beat my edit by about 4 seconds, can you check that? If not I can make a separate question.

Comment: @klayala23 is the new condition, `df %>% mutate(check_column = case_when(column1 %in% c("Closed", "pending") ~ "Check", TRUE ~ "Error"))`

Comment: @klayala23 i updated the answer.  May be that helps. thanks